# Datatable shows only one entry

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, datatables, google-cloud-firestore

I have retrieved data from a firestore collection and stored them within an array. I have used that array to inject the data into a datatable but the datatable once loaded displays only one entry but I have fetched all documents within the firestore collection. What could be the problem? Below is the javascript  code and html

```html
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:fit-content; " id="mydatatable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Document id</th>
      <th scope="col">title</th>
      <th scope="col">details</th>
      <th scope="col">timestamp</th>
      <th scope="col">name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody id="tableBody">
  </tbody>

  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Document id</th>
      <th scope="col">title</th>
      <th scope="col">details</th>
      <th scope="col">timestamp</th>
      <th scope="col">name</th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

```js
var table = document.getElementById('tableBody');
var tableData = new Array();

db.collection("Emergency_Feeds").orderBy("timestamp", "desc").onSnapshot(function (querySnapshot) {

  querySnapshot.docChanges().forEach(function (change) {

    console.log('documents retrieved successfully');
    console.log(`is here: ${change.doc.id} => ${change.doc.data().name}`);

    var documentId = change.doc.id;
    var username = change.doc.data().name;
    var emTitle = change.doc.data().title;
    var emDets = change.doc.data().details;
    var emTimeDate = change.doc.data().timestamp.toDate();

    if (change.type === "added") {
      tableData = [
        [
          documentId,
          emTimeDate,
          emTitle,
          emDets,
          username
        ]
      ]

      $('#mydatatable').DataTable({
        retrieve: true,
        data: tableData
      });
    }

    if (change.type === "modified") {
      tableData = [
        [
          documentId,
          emTimeDate,
          emTitle,
          emDets,
          username
        ]
      ]

      $('#mydatatable').DataTable({
        retrieve: true,
        data: tableData
      });
    }

    if (change.type === "removed") {
      tableData = [
        [
          documentId,
          emTimeDate,
          emTitle,
          emDets,
          username
        ]
      ]

      $('#mydatatable').DataTable({
        retrieve: true,
        data: tableData
      });
    }
  });
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot#docchanges), `querySnapshot.docChanges()`

> Returns an array of the documents changes since the last snapshot. If
>   this is the first snapshot, all documents will be in the list as added
>   changes.

By calling `forEach` on this Array you are looping over the different [`DocumentChange`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentChange), and **for each change** you are redefining the content of the data table with this one specific `DocumentChange`. Therefore your table has only one element.

So you should correctly manage the table data population by adding/replacing/removing only the corresponding `DocumentChange`, using [Array methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) like [`push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push), [`splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice), etc. . Something along the following lines (untested):

```
var table = document.getElementById('tableBody');
var tableData = new Array();

db.collection("Emergency_Feeds").orderBy("timestamp", "desc").onSnapshot(function (querySnapshot) {

  querySnapshot.docChanges().forEach(function (change) {

    console.log('documents retrieved successfully');
    console.log(`is here: ${change.doc.id} => ${change.doc.data().name}`);

    var documentId = change.doc.id;
    var username = change.doc.data().name;
    var emTitle = change.doc.data().title;
    var emDets = change.doc.data().details;
    var emTimeDate = change.doc.data().timestamp.toDate();

    if (change.type === "added") {
      tableData.push(
        [
          documentId,
          emTimeDate,
          emTitle,
          emDets,
          username
      ]);

    }

    if (change.type === "modified") {
        //..... 
        //Here update the table element
        // Note that the DocumentChange contains the old and new index
    }

    if (change.type === "removed") {
        //..... 
        //Here remove the table element
    }
  });

  $('#mydatatable').DataTable({
      retrieve: true,
      data: tableData
  });

});
```